# How to add in dynamic parameters into a graphql query

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

I want to make a **GraphQL** query that takes in some data from the data field of my Vue app. However, when I set up the variables hook and try to reference the object I need by using this.object, I get a cannot read 'xxx' of undefined.

```
apollo: {
    question: {
      query: gql `
      query question($id: Int!) {
        question(id: $id){
          ...
        }
      }
`, variables: { id: this.presentQuestionId}
    }
  },
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'presentQuestionId' of undefined is the error message that keeps on coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`variables`** option should be a function that returns an object like :

```
variables(){
    return{
     id: this.presentQuestionId
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure JS I sometimes use this trick:

```
const opts = {foo: 1, bar: 2}
const q = gql`
    query Query {
        getSomething(
            par1: ${opts.foo}
            ${!!opts.bar ? `, par2: ${opts.bar}` : ''}
        ) {
            id
            name
        }
    }
`
```

If **par2** defined it adds to query.